# PHP encoding program with TM

Tags: php, urlencode

So in PHP I am trying to open a URL using;

```
$raw = file_get_contents($inlink);
```

and then I am working on the results.  $inlin come from a $_GET variable.  This works for most URLs but I have an issue when the URL includes the TM (™) symbol as I get a 404 error.

The URL in question is http://www.boots.com/en/Soap-Glory-Flake-Away-™-Body-Scrub-300ml_27894/

So it seems like an encoding issue.  So I have tried urlencode, but this doesn't help.  I have also tried copy and past from the address bar in firefox, so that I enter

```
http://www.boots.com/en/Soap-Glory-Flake-Away-%E2%84%A2-Body-Scrub-300ml_27894/
```

instead, but this also does not help.

Through debugging and echoing to the screen then I end up with either

```
http://www.boots.com/en/Soap-Glory-Flake-Away-â„¢-Body-Scrub-300ml_27894/
```

or

```
http%3A%2F%2Fwww.boots.com%2Fen%2FSoap-Glory-Flake-Away-%E2%84%A2-Body-Scrub-300ml_27894%2F
```

being submitted, neither of which works.

Strange thing, is that if I hard code the link in the program then it works!

Any ideas?

Comment: Doesn't quite belong to your question but a short heads-up: Make sure that ONLY AUTHORIZED users may use this function. If you allow guests to do this, they might probably request ANY url using YOUR SERVER. Thus, you'll be responsible for any abusement done using this service in the first line. Also, they can cause you tons of traffic. You really don't want this.

Comment: The system is for registered users only, and only a very few URLs are allowed to be opened in this way.  But thanks for the pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `utf8_encode` the URL (I assume it comes by in ISO-8859-1(5)/Latin1)

Also, I assume you are utf8_decoding and validating the URL before you run the `file_get_contents()` - you wouldn't want a user to make *your system* request an arbitrary URL from anywhere on the Internet.